# How can one say the Novena to St. Michael?

Tags: catholicism, michael, novenas

I want to start a novena to St Michael. Found one at [Novena in honor of St. Michael the Archangel and in honour of the nine angelic choirs](http://maryourhelp.org/St-michael-the-arch-angel-novena.html) .

How can I say it as there is no specific guide on the page?

Answer (score 5):

Novenas are an ancient part of the the Church’s devotional life. Many trace the structure back to the nine days between Jesus’ ascension and the feast of Pentecost. A novena (meaning “nine days”) is a special time of prayer, typically for a specific intention.

In the treasury of Catholic prayers there exists many novenas to St. Michael the Archangel that may be prayed during any time of the year, but is a most fitting preparation for his feast day on September 29.

Unfortunately the website you noted in your question is rather poorly done and makes it somewhat confusing to those who wish to pray a true novena by simply listing various prayers to St. Michael the Archangel without any clarification. The website seems to list different possible novenas on its' page.

For example the Chaplet of St. Michael the Archangel is used by many of the faithful as a novena in itself, just as others use the Litany of St. Michael as a novena. I myself have done both of these, but not together.

For a [novena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novena_to_Saint_Michael) to St. Michael, I would suggest that you perhaps pray one of the traditional ones such as the following:

> Saint Michael the Archangel, loyal champion of God and His People. I turn to you with confidence and seek your powerful intercession. For the love of God, Who made you so glorious in grace and power, and for the love of the Mother of Jesus, the Queen of the Angels, be pleased to hear our prayer. You know the value of our souls in the eyes of God. May no stain of evil ever disfigure its beauty. Help us to conquer the evil spirit who tempts us. We desire to imitate your loyalty to God and Holy Mother and your great love for God and people. And since you are God’s messenger for the care of His people, we entrust to you these special intentions:...**specific intentions are stated here**....Lord, hear and grant our special intentions for this Novena. Amen.

Answer (score 3):

From the [*The Raccolta or Collection of indulgenced prayers and good works*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3456):

> ###290. Novena of St Michael.
> […]
>
> N. B. The Novena may be made at any time of the year, and **with any form of prayers sanctioned by
> competent ecclesiastical authority**.

Thus, if you say any approved St. Michael prayer* everyday for 9 days, you fulfill the conditions of the novena.
<sup>*for example, [the full St. Michael Prayer](http://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Angeli/StMLeoXIII.html) (≠ the "formula of exorcism against Satan and the fallen angels" or full exorcism prayers, [which only approved exorcists should pray](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_19850924_exorcism_en.html))</sup>